# Add a Listener to Jtable which is called once and only once when the table is populated

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable which gets populated upon some search. I tried to add a TableModelListener but it is called for each row/column updated.

But I want the listener to be called only once when the table is updated, no matter how many rows are inserted.

Comment: You need to use the `TableModelListener` and discard the events you don't need

Comment: Have you tried overriding the class `TableModelListener` in order to implement the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`TableModelListener` is a jack of all events for `JTable`, inserts, updates, deletes, the whole lot.  You need to inspect the `TableModelEvent` and use the properties to determine what type of event is been triggered.

From having a look at the source code for `TableModelEvent` and `AbstractTableModel`, it would seem that the `tableDataChanged` event can be identified when `TableModelEvent#getType` is equal to `TableModelEvent.UPDATE` and `TabelModelEvent#geColumn` is equal to `TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..
In the tableChanged(...) method I have added the condtions for type of event.
Actually the problem is that the listener is invoked for all the records inserted one by one and since the added records are in 1000s it never seems to stop.

Comment: Yep, that's how TableModelListener works, hence the reasons I suggest monitoring for the type of event. I'll a little more digging, but that's essentially the basic information provided by the event

Answer (score 0):

> I have a JTable which gets populated upon some search

A search implies a logical block of code that finds rows of data to be inserted into the table at one time.

> But I want the listener to be called only once when the table is updated, no matter how many rows are inserted.

If you use the addRow(...) method then an event is generated for each row. If you don't like this then don't add one row at a time.

Instead you create a List of rows to be added, then you create an `insertRows(...)` method in your TableModel. This method would then only generate a single event.

For example check out the `insertRows(...)` method found in the [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). You would need to add a method like this to your TableModel.